Is the Lorentz force proportional to $B$-field in the wire or immediately outside of it?
When considering the force on a current carrying wire in a magnetic field, is $B$ in the Lorentz force $F=IlB$ the field inside the wire where the current is flowing, or is it the field immediately outside the wire?
To put it another way, is the Lorentz force greater on a piece of iron than a piece of copper (because iron has a high permeability), given the same current and H field? And if not, then does a wire experience a greater force when the entire circuit is in air rather than submerged in water (because air has a higher permeability than water)?
If the Lorentz force depends on $B$ immediately outside of the wire, how does this not violate localism? Why are the electrons being pushed to the side by the magnetic field outside the wire when they're inside the wire?
To be absolutely clear, I'm not talking about the production of the H field due to the motion of electrons in the wire. You may assume the H field is uniform everywhere. The B field only differs as the permeability of the substance differs.

In the formula for magnetic force on current-conducting wire element of length $L$:
$$
\mathbf F =  I\mathbf  L \times \mathbf B,
$$
$\mathbf B$ refers to external magnetic field $\mathbf B_{ext}$, due to sources other than those in the element of the wire of length $L$; and it refers to value of this external field at the point of space where the current flows. Usually, most of the current flows inside the wire (as opposed to its surface), thus $B$ in the formula refers to external magnetic induction inside the wire. However, since $\mathbf B_{ext}$ is continuous in the region where the wire element is present, and source of the external magnetic field is usually quite distant (compared to length $L$), value of this external magnetic field at the surface is almost the same as inside the wire, so usually the difference is negligible.
If the wire is thick or the source of the external magnetic field is very close, so $\mathbf B_{ext}$ varies throughout the cross-section of the wire, then we can use the integral formula taking this into account:
$$
\mathbf F = \int \mathbf j \times \mathbf B~ d^3\mathbf x.
$$
Here  $\mathbf B$ is assumed to be a function of position, and integral goes over all points of space where current density $\mathbf j$ is non-zero. Thus macroscopic magnetic force on a wire can be expressed as sum of forces on all current elements in the wire (due to moving charge), and is proportional to product of current density and external magnetic field at the position of the element.

As ridiculous as this sounds, when I said "immediately outside the wire", I meant the air or free space surrounding it, and not the surface of the wire, which I recognize with have the same or nearly the same permeability. And I know, it makes no sense to say the force is proportional to the magnetic field outside the wire, but I had two physicists whom I respect claim this, so I had to double check.

Thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Maybe there was just a miscommunication/misunderstanding. There are other formulae for magnetic force, and one of them, using the Maxwell stress tensor, expresses net force on a body using electric and magnetic field on any imaginary surface containing the body. Thus field "just outside the wire" can be used there. The resulting force will be the same as using the above formula.

Does this imply that if a current-carrying wire of permeability $\mu_0$ feels a force $F$, then the same wire but of permeability $\mu_r\mu_0$ feels a force $\mu_rF$?

@RileyScottJacob No. $\mu_r$ characterizes how well the conductor magnetizes. This does not affect the above magnetic force. It does affect the net force a little, because there is also another force, proportional to product of magnetic moment and gradient of external magnetic field, but this is usually considered negligible when the above force is present.

@JánLalinský That was my understanding as well. Thank you for the clarification.

Neither. The magnetic field in the Lorentz force equation is the magnetic field due to all current sources other than the wire itself.
One could in principle look at the forces on each microscopic element of the wire. Each element of the wire would feel forces from two sources: from external fields, and from the currents (free and bound) inside the wire. Wires made of different materials will certainly have different amounts of bound currents. But as far as the net force on the wire goes, the bound currents don't matter; because when we sum up all the microscopic forces on the elements of the wire to obtain the net force, all of the forces internal to the site will cancel out (thanks, Newton!) and only the forces from the external fields will matter.

I think the OP is asking how you handle the magnetic field due to other current sources if the field changes due to material properties in the wire

@BioPhysicist:  That was my point about the bound currents, etc.  Even if the total magnetic field at any point inside the wire differs due to the wire's material properties, the resulting differences in the forces will automatically cancel out when we figure out the net force on the wire.


as far as the net force on the wire goes, the bound currents don't matter; because when we sum up all the microscopic forces on the elements of the wire to obtain the net force, all of the forces internal to the site will cancel out -- Magnetic forces, in general, do not obey Newton's third law. In general, bound currents may affect net external force on any wire element. It is not clear that these effects sum up to zero for the given wire or circuit.


@JánLalinský:  I'm aware of a a few exceptions to Newton's Third Law in the context of magnetic fields, but those all involve time-dependent fields or currents that don't obey $\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = 0$ (which is secretly the same thing.) It would be interesting to do the explicit calculations to confirm that the self-force on a long wire is zero, but I would be shocked if it isn't.  Maybe once I've got my grades in.

That said, I suppose that if you have an external field that's non-uniform, the distribution of bound currents in the interior of the wire could affect the net force.  The idea that the field is uniform is implicit in the formula $F = I l B$, though;  if $B$ is non-uniform then the force has to be written as an integral over the length of the wire instead.

This answer misses the point. I understand that a small segment of wire dl doesn't generate it's own H-field to interact with (or to the extent it does, it cancels itself out). I want to know if the H-field is generated elsewhere, then when we calculate the B, there's B in the wire and outside the wire. I've been told by other physicists that the force uses B immediately outside the wire, which makes no sense to me.

@JosephSummerhays: I guess I don't see why you should have to think about $\vec{H}$. The Lorentz force on each element of the wire only depends on $\vec{B}$ experienced by the element, not $\vec{H}$. And if you look at it in terms of the $\vec{B}$'s produced by the current and by the external agents, then it's obvious that only the external fields matter.

The H field matters only because $B=\mu H$. B is not produced (directly) by currents. H is produced by currents. B is produced by the interaction between H and the permeability of the material. I don't love that you say "only external fields matter". I know what you mean, you mean fields that are local to the wire but produced by currents external to the wire. But it sounds like the field outside the wire, when that's not what you mean (I think).

@JosephSummerhays it's  misleading to think of $H$ as produced by only currents. When magnetized body is present, $H$ is affected by its magnetization as well, irrespective of presence of currents. None of this matters for the force formula above, because in this formula, only $B$ appears.
